# Does Python support conditional structure in regex?

Tags: python, regex

Does Python support conditional structure in regex?

1. If yes, why I can't have the following (using lookahead in the if
   part) right? Any way to make Python support it?

   ```
   >>> p = re.compile(r'(?(?=regex)then|else)')
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
       return _compile(pattern, flags)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
       raise error, v # invalid expression
   sre_constants.error: bad character in group name
   ```
2. Using backreference as the if part works, however:

   ```
   >>> p = re.compile(r'(expr)?(?(1)then|else)')
   ```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html says

> Conditionals are supported by the JGsoft engine, Perl, PCRE, **Python**,
>   and the .NET framework.

What is the closest solution to use conditionals in regex?

My Python is 2.7.3. I don't know how to check the version of `re` module (how can I?). Thanks.

Comment: probably not, it's not working in the latest python 3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation you referenced:

> Python supports conditionals using a numbered or named capturing group. Python does not support conditionals using lookaround, even though Python does support lookaround outside conditionals. **Instead of a conditional like `(?(?=regex)then|else)`, you can alternate two opposite lookarounds: `(?=regex)then|(?!regex)else)`.**

Comment: thanks. What are some popular languages that support using lookaround in the if part?

Comment: @Tim, I don't have absolute answer for that. At least, I know that perl support it: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f(condition)yes-pattern%7cno-pattern)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a online tester that can test the conditional with lookaround as the if part. I tried some, but havent found one working yet.