# If-then & lookahead with parentheses in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a small project that involves grepping through .py files and picking out import statements only of the form `from <x> import <y>`.

In building a regex to capture this, there are two distinct syntaxes involved, best illustrated by example:

Syntax #1 uses parentheses and can have newlines enclosed in those parentheses:

```
from .sql.base import (
    SchemaVisitor
    )
import os  # ignore this import
from _pytest.config import (
    main, UsageError, cmdline,
    hookspec, hookimpl
)
```

I can capture this with:

```
syntax1 = re.compile(r'^ *from (?P<package>[.\w]+) +import +\(?(?P<objects>[*, \n\w]+)\)? *$',
                     flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Syntax #2 uses line continutation (if needed), and technically has no newlines within the import statement:

```
from pandas import Series

from .solvers import solve, solve_linear_system, solve_linear_system_LU, \
    solve_undetermined_coeffs, nsolve, solve_linear, checksol, \
    det_quick, inv_quick, check_assumptions

from .ode import checkodesol, classify_ode, dsolve, \
    homogeneous_order
```

I can capture this with:

```
# Only difference: no `\n` in <objects> group
syntax2 = re.compile(r'^ *from (?P<package>[.\w]+) +import +(?P<objects>[*, \w]+) *$',
                     flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

I would like to condense these into one statement capable of zipping up the named groups all at once.

What it seems like I need here is an **if-then conditional with a positive lookahead.**  Something like:

```
syntax = re.compile(r'^ *from (?P<package>[.\w]+) +import +(?(?=\([^)]+\))\((?P<obj1>[*, \n\w]+)\) *$|(?P<obj2>[*, \w]+) *$)',
                    flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

This seems to follow the syntax of `(?ifthen|else)` with a lookahead for the `if`, i.e.

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

where:

- the `if` is `(?=\([^)]+\))`: parentheses enclosing some text that is not parentheses
- the `then` is `\((?P<obj1>[*, \n\w]+)\) *$`
- the `else` is `(?P<obj2>[*, \w]+) *$)`

What do I have wrong here?

**Input:**

```
imports = """
from .sql.base import (
    SchemaVisitor
    )

from pandas import Series as ser, DataFrame as df
from NumPy import array

import os
import functools

import ctypes  # ignore these

from _pytest.config import (
    main, UsageError, cmdline,
    hookspec, hookimpl
)

from .solvers import solve, solve_linear_system, solve_linear_system_LU, \
    solve_undetermined_coeffs, nsolve, solve_linear, checksol, \
    det_quick, inv_quick, check_assumptions

from .ode import checkodesol, classify_ode, dsolve, \
    homogeneous_order
"""
```

**Desired result:**

```
syntax.findall(imports)

[('.sql.base', '\n    SchemaVisitor\n    '),
 ('pandas', 'Series\n'),
 ('_pytest.config', '\n    main, UsageError, cmdline,\n    hookspec, hookimpl\n'),
 ('.solvers', 'solve, solve_linear_system, solve_linear_system_LU,     solve_undetermined_coeffs, nsolve, solve_linear, checksol,     det_quick, inv_quick, check_assumptions\n'),
 ('.ode', 'checkodesol, classify_ode, dsolve,     homogeneous_order\n')]
```

Comment: Please check this https://regex101.com/r/uGzBqp/1

Comment: Like this https://regex101.com/r/7rRz81/1 ?

Comment: I think this might be your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123348/314922

Comment: Are the newline characters desired in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^\ *from\s+
    (?P<package_name>[.\w]+)\s+
    import\s+
    (\()?
    (?(2)
        (?P<object>[^()]+)\)
        |
        (?P<object2>(?:.+[\n\r]?)+)
    )
''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

def aftermatch(group1, group2):
    group = group1 if group1 else group2
    objects = [obj.strip() for obj in group.split(',')]
    return objects

packages = {m.group('package_name'): aftermatch(m.group('object'), m.group('object2'))
            for m in rx.finditer(data)}
print(packages)
```

---

Which yields for your string `imports`:

```
{'.sql.base': ['SchemaVisitor'], 'pandas': ['Series'], '_pytest.config': ['main', 'UsageError', 'cmdline', 'hookspec', 'hookimpl'], '.solvers': ['solve', 'solve_linear_system', 'solve_linear_system_LU', 'solve_undetermined_coeffs', 'nsolve', 'solve_linear', 'checksol', 'det_quick', 'inv_quick', 'check_assumptions'], '.ode': ['checkodesol', 'classify_ode', 'dsolve', 'homogeneous_order']}
```

---

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7rRz81/1/),  the rest is a dict comprehension with a function called `aftermatch()` to clean the object part afterwards.

---

**Edit:** For *non-sticklers*, you could use the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which supports branch resets. Here, you do not need a function anymore:

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^from\s+
    (?P<package_name>[.\w]+)\s+
    import\s+
    (?|
        \((?P<object>[^()]+)\)
        |   
        (?P<object>(?:.+[\n\r]?)+)
    )
''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

packages = {m.group('package_name'): 
            [obj.strip() for obj in m.group('object').split(',')]
            for m in rx.finditer(imports)}
print(packages)
```

Answer (score -1):

The if else functionality is technically possible, you just need to think about it in terms of the '|' statement.

```
^ *from (?P<package>[.\w]+) +import (\()?(?(2)(?P<object0>[*, \n\w]+)\)|(?P<object1>[*, \w]+))
```

If the expression before the | is not matched then select the expression after the |. In effect this is essentially an if then else if you include the if with the then part of the statement.

Comment: `(\()?` can just be `\(?`, no?